# cvSetCaptureProperty CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES property not working with OpenMP

Tags: opencv, openmp, visual-c++-2012

I'm a complete noob using openCV and openMP and I really want to understand why the cvSetCaptureProperty  is not working with openMP. I'm using OpenCV and OpenMP on Visual Studio 2012.

My code:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (int i=0;i<3600;i++)
{
     cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,i);
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    i++;
}
```

The error message it returns me:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x71648EAB (opencv_ffmpeg248.dll) in pupilometry.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFEEEFEF6.
```

Someone know how to use cvSetCaptureProperty in a parallel way?

Thanks

Comment: hmm, the videocapture is already running in its own thread... applying omp here might be a bad idea.

Comment: Hello berak! I need to paralelize things like `cvSmooth`, `cvThreshold` and `cvCanny`. Do u know any way to do it? I was just starting by trying to make the frame query parallel. Please HELP!!!!!

Comment: you must not make queryframe parallel, instead, use the frame which you grabbed, make the copies of it, use each one in different processes, one for smooth, threshold and canny

Comment: 4nonymou5, thanks for ur reply! So, now, how to paralelize smooth, threshold and canny? Does  #pragma omp parallel and #pragma omp section works in this case? Thanks